# Ask turtles to move to patch that is their state variable

Tags: netlogo

In my model, I have turtles that start at a random location.  This location is then saved as a state variable `home-xy` using the `patch-here` command.  It is thus stored as format `(patch 234 345)`.  I then want my turtles to return to this location at the end of a procedure.  I've tried the following two pieces of code:

```
ask turtles [
   move-to home-xy
]

ask turtles [
   let x [pxcor] of home-xy
   let y [pycor] of home-xy   
   move-to patch x y 
]
```

These do not work, but I think they represent my problem well enough.  Thank you.

Comment: How bad it doesn't work? Note that you are not saving the exact location of turtles - if you are OK with approximate location of patches, it should work fine. Is the `home-xy` variable declared inside the `turtles-own` section?

Comment: Agree, `move-to home-xy` should work just fine. It will help us help you if you show actual code and not just descriptions ("this location is then saved").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why your first code didn't work. I just tested this and it's fine (returns to the centre of the patch where it started):

```
turtles-own [home-xy]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set home-xy patch-here ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
end

to go-home
  ask turtles [ move-to home-xy ]
end
```

You might want to inspect a turtle and make sure that home-xy is being set properly.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems I was sprouting some agents and not setting their "home-xy".